# VBA Excel SQL Query Between '5:00:00' and '12:00:00' (solo time not date)

Tags: sql, vba, excel

The source is in the format:
time hh:mm:ss.

I need to get records between two times.

```
select * from [Raport$] WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,'time',108) between '09:00:00' and '11:00:00';
```

This code doesn't work... why?
Error Message:
Undefinde function 'Convert'; Run-time error -2147217900 (80040e14)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: This code don't work... why?

Comment: What does don't work mean, does it throw an error, what is the error? Does it produce unepected results, provide an [mcve].

Comment: If `time` is a column name, use it as `time` instead of `'time'`

Comment: Yes, Time is a column (recordset) name. After swap still doesn't work...

Comment: What database environment are you pointed at? Your error code suggests `CONVERT` is not an accepted function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the record sourced from SQL Server? If so try the below :

```
SELECT * FROM [Reports$] WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), [Time], 108) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '11:00:00'
```

If datatype of column [Time] is datetime then the above pull records of all the dates, use another condition in where for date

```
SELECT * FROM [Reports$] WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), [Time], 108) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '11:00:00' AND CONVERT(varchar(10), [Time], 101) = 'ANYDATE(dd/MM/yyyy)'
```

Comment: Column[Time] got only hh:mm:ss formatted data without date: yyyy/mm/dd. This is part of VBA-excel code database is in .xlsx. Connection sting, is ok. Still same error. Connection by ADODB.

Comment: ok, considering Time column having hh:mm:ss formatted text - try `select * from [Reports$] where FORMAT([Time],'hh:mm:ss') between '09:00:00' And '11:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [Raport$] WHERE Time Between #09:00:00# And #18:00:00#
```

worked for me.

Comment: Yes, code work but RecordCount = 0 ... so it doesn't recognize time value.